# using sidebar in different blades

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I'm a newbie in laravel and actually I have to write the sidebar in every blade of the application to make it work, but I'd like using a different sidebar depending on the section of the site where I am. 
So this is what I'm trying to do:

***EDIT 1***

**layouts/main.blade.php**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="sidebar" data-color="brown" data-active-color="danger">
      <div class="logo">
         <!-- Content -->
      </div>
      <!-- Sidebar -->
      @if(request()->is("{{ url('/')}}/{operator}"))
         @include('operator.sidebar')
      @else
         @include('stduser.sidebar')
      @endif
      <!-- End sidebar -->
   </div>

   <div class="main-panel">
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <nav></nav>
      <!-- End navbar -->

      <!-- Main content section -->
      @yield('main-panel')
      <!-- End main content section -->

      <!-- Footer -->
      <footer></footer>
      <!-- End footer -->
   </div>
</div>
```

**stduser/dashboard.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('main-panel')
   <!-- Main panel contents -->
@endsection

@section('extrajs')
   <!-- script contents -->
@endsection
```

**stduser/sidebar.blade.php**

```
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="user btn-rotate">
     <div class="photo">
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="info">
        <a href="{{ url('/user') }}/profile">
           <span>
              {{ Auth::user()->name }}
           </span>
        </a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav">
     <li class="active btn-rotate">
        <a href="{{ url('/') }}">
           <i class="nc-icon nc-bank"></i>
           <p>Companies</p>
        </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**operator/sidebar.blade.php**

```
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="user btn-rotate">
     <div class="photo">
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="info">
        <a href="{{ url('/user') }}/profile">
           <span>
              {{ Auth::user()->name }}
           </span>
        </a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav">
     <li class="active btn-rotate">
        <a href="{{ url('/') }}/{{ $operator->id }}/about">
           <i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <p>DashBoard</p>
        </a>
     </li>
     <li class="btn-rotate">
        <a href="{{ url('/')}}/{{ $operator->id}}/suppliers">
           <i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <p>Suppliers</p>
        </a>
     </li>
     <li class="btn-rotate">
        <a href="{{ url('/')}}/{{ $operator->id}}/products">
           <i class="fa fa-product-hunt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <p>Products</p>
        </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is how my views are structured:

[image]

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

you can include the blade file like so @include('layouts/sidebar_' . $sidebarName) and if you want to avoid errors when include doesnt exist you can use @includeIf('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])

So you have just the include statement and the sidebar content only once

Comment: Should I switch _@include_ with _@yield_ in **stduser/dashboard.blade.php**?

Comment: no, you just can include the template were you want to use it :) no need for yield or section in it :)

Comment: but in _operator_ folder I have to create another sidebar cause it will have a different nav. I edited the question so you can understand better my problem

Comment: then in your main layout you could do it this way @include("{$user->role()}/sidebar')

and your role() could return operator, stduser or layouts, or maybe use a more appropriate method name here. just so get hat you wanted

Answer (score 1):

Based on your feedback to addi2113's answer, it seems like you're wanting to switch out the sidebar include based on which page you're on. There are several ways to do this. The simplest (yet least flexible) way to do this would be to show a certain sidebar based on the route. For instance, if you have a predictable route structure for all "operator" pages, such as example.com/operator/*, you could do the following by using an @if statement in your blade view. Like this:

```
@if(request()->is("/unique/url/pattern"))
    @include('operator.sidebar')
@else
    @include('stduser.sidebar')
@endif
```

Obviously, you can edit this to use any logic you want, but this is a somewhat simple way to handle this.

EDIT: Try this in your main.blade instead of using a section and yield:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar" data-color="brown" data-active-color="danger">
      <div class="logo">
         <!-- Content -->
      </div>
      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="user btn-rotate">
           <div class="photo">
              <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff"></i>
           </div>
           <div class="info">
              <a href="{{ url('/') }}/profile">
                 <span>
                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                 </span>
              </a>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
        @if(request()->is('/unique/url/pattern'))
             @include('operator.sidebar')
        @else
             @include('stduser.sidebar')
        @endif
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2:

Since it appears you are using a dynamic URL for the operator pages, you have two options. The first option is to make your operator routes more unique than they currently are so that you can use an asterisk to denote all routes of a current pattern. For instance, in routes/web.php, change your routes for operator pages to this type of pattern:

```
Route::get('/operator/{operator}/about','OperatorController@about')->name('operator-about');
```

By adding the operator slug into the url, you now have a UNIQUE path that you can reference. Then, in your main blade, you would reference all of the operator routes together like this:

```
@if(request()->is('/operator/*'))
     @include('operator.sidebar')
```

By making the URL unique, you have made a very simple way to reference all routes where you want to show the operator sidebar.

Another option, which is not as robust in my opinion, is to refer to the specific routes by naming. For instance, using the route I defined up above with the name of "operator-about", I could show the operator sidebar like this:

```
@if(Route::currentRouteName()=="operator-about")
     @include('operator.sidebar')
```

You would then expand upon this by explicitly defining all named routes that you would want to show the operator sidebar for. As you can probably tell, this will get messy if there are a lot of routes you want to include. I don't recommend to do it this way, but you can feel free to solve the problem however you want.

Comment: it's not a role, it's simply a section of the same user. _Operator_ folder is a company of the logged user, so in stduser.dashboard I choose a company, I want that different sidebar

Comment: To be more accurate, it's not another sidebar. As you can see is just an append of the same sidebar.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Your folder structure shows two distinct blades. Right now you are "yielding" a sidebar. It seems like what you want to do is include a sidebar and change it based on your URL structure. But I guess maybe I'm not understanding your situation well enough.

Comment: operator is a section's user, not a role such as user or admin. As you can see, the blade appends the final part of sidebar. It's not a completely new one.

Comment: My code doesn't really care about that. I am saying to adjust what you display based on the URL structure, not the user role. My example showed "operator/*" as an example URL, but you can change it to whatever fits your use case. You should know based on the URL what section of the site your user is looking at. Based on that, you will know what sidebar to display. And it can all be switched out in an if statement wrapped around an include

Comment: I am going to use your code to show you what I mean. Editing my answer now.

Comment: I can't show the operator sidebar. I'm editing the question so you can see

Comment: You aren't including the blade properly. You don't link to a blade by using a route. Based on your folder structure your includes should look like this: @include('operator.sidebar') and @include('stduser.sidebar'). I'm editing my answer to include this structure.

Comment: Feel free to PM me if you want more help. I am not sure that the url pattern you are specifying with the requestI()->is() function will work as you expect. You may need to name the route and then use Route::currerntRouteName() function to see if the current route matches that route name.

Comment: What if I'm using an id in url? How can I handle it with your method?

Comment: Name your route. I will edit my answer to show you shortly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182799/discussion-between-eresourcesinc-and-gabax).